# Python discord bot main func returning ''asycnio.run() cannot be called from a running event loop"

Tags: python-3.x, async-await, discord, python-asyncio, chatbot

Me and a friend are working on a discord bot. We managed to get the bot to run in our IDEs (Pycharm and VS), however when I try to transfer the code to another machine (like my rasberry pi) the bot logs into discord but doesn't load any of the cog files (which have all of its commands). This is the error it gives me

> Line 27 bot.load.extension (f"Cog.{file[:-3]") RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'BotBase.load_extension' was never awaited bot.load.extension (f"Cog.{file[:-3]"}

Again, this error never came up in our IDEs. I was however able to get around this by changing the main function into a async func but this time I got a different error.

> Line 33 asycnio.run(main()) discord.ext.commands.errors.ExtensionFailed: Extension 'Cog.help_cog' raised an error:Type Error: object NoneType can't be used in await expression

(*Note: all the cog files have this error)

Heres the full code (not including the cog files)

`
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import random, os, requests, json, ffmpeg
import asyncio

```
from dotenv import load_dotenv
load_dotenv()

intents = discord.Intents().all()

TOKEN = os.getenv('BOT_TOKEN')

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="$", help_command=None, intents=intents, owner_ids={REDACTED})

async def main():
  for file in os.listdir("./Cog"):
    if file.endswith(".py"):
      await bot.load_extension(f"Cog.{file[:-3]}")
  bot.run(TOKEN)



if __name__ == "__main__":
  asyncio.run(main())`
```

I honestly don't know where to start with this. The bot is supposed to log into discord and then load the cog files, but its only doing the former and not the latter. Both me and my friend are amateurs, so forgive me if the solution is something trivial and simple. If anyone has any ideas on how to fix this I would be extremely grateful.

Edit:

Ok so I realized the problem. The Cog files have two lines of code that weren't being awaited.

```
def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog('FILE'_cog(bot))
```

Pretty stupid mistake on my part. I simply added async and await to these, however I now get another error:

> RunTimeError: asycio.run() cannot be called from a running event loop
> sys:1: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'Client.run..runner' was never awaited

Answer (score 0):

You are working with relative paths. This doesn't work on linux, and instead an absolute path should be provided. An option is to use the pathlib Path:

```
from pathlib import Path


path_to_file = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.joinpath('Cogs', 'YOUR_COG_FILE.py')
```

Comment: The files are being loaded, so I don't think theres a problem with paths. Also I use linux on my main computer (the one I used to write the code) and it works just fine.

Comment: The os is maybe not the issue here..